# BASH script with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I'm currently writing a little script in bash to ask the user for some setting. The script is asking some infos, and then run other scripts. I have to run it under sudo, because I have some apt-get install in scripts.

But when I launch it with sudo, I have this error :

```
./install_all: 1: ./install_all: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Here is the beginning of my script :

```
function askAllInfo() {
    echo -e "
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
    |     Choix de la version de PHP     | 
    |                                    |
    |              1.) PHP5              |
    |              2.) PHP7              |
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#\n"

    read -e -p "Selectionner la version PHP pour l'installation de Maarch (PHP5) : " phpVERSION
    if [ "$phpVERSION" == "1" ] || [ "$phpVERSION" == "" ]; then
        phpVersion='5'
    elif [ "$phpVERSION" == "2" ]; then
        phpVersion='7'
    fi

    echo -e "
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
    |    Choix du chemin d'installation de MAARCH :    |
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#\n"
    read -e -p "Merci de spécifier le chemin pour l'installation de Maarch (/var/www/maarch_courrier) : " maarchURL
    if [ "$maarchURL" == "" ]; then
        MAARCH_SITE=/var/www/maarch_courrier
    else
        MAARCH_SITE=$maarchURL
    fi

    echo -e "
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
    |    Choix du chemin des docservers :    |
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#\n"
    read -e -p "Merci de spécifier le chemin des docservers (/var/docserver) : " docserversURL
    if [ "$docserversURL" == "" ]; then
        DOCSERVER_PATH=/var/docserver
    else
        DOCSERVER_PATH=$docserversURL
    fi

    echo -e "
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
    |        Choix du nom de la BDD :        |
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#\n"
    read -e -p "Merci de spécifier le nom de la base de donnée (maarch) : " databaseName
    if [ "$databaseName" == "" ]; then
        DATABASE_NAME=maarch
    else
        DATABASE_NAME=$databaseName
    fi

    echo -e "
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
    |        Choix du login de l'utilisateur de la BDD :        |
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#\n"
    read -e -p "Merci de spécifier le login de l'utilisateur de la base de donnée (postgres) : " databaseUser
    if [ "$databaseUser" == "" ]; then
        DATABASE_USER=postgres
    else
        DATABASE_USER=$databaseUser
    fi

    echo -e "
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
    |          Choix du mdp de l'utilisateur de la BDD :        |
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#\n"
    read -e -p "Merci de spécifier le mot de passe de l'utilisateur de la base de donnée (postgres) : " databasePass
    if [ "$databasePass" == "" ]; then
        DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
    else
        DATABASE_USER=$databasePass
    fi
}

askAllInfo
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @cxw, thanks a lot, it resolve my problem. I didn't think of this at all, how dumb I am ? ahah

Comment: @JohnKugelman And there many many subtle ways how to create slightly invalid bash code. Just one example: some bash guru told me for example that you always go for `${variable}` and that you always always always use `[[` instead of "[". In my eyes, bash is one of those languages that make it **super easy** for doing the wrong thing; and you don't even notice until (too) late.

Comment: You do not need to run the entire script under sudo.  Just invoke sudo from within the script on the specific commands that require elevated privileges.

Comment: Consider whether it actually *needs* to be a `bash` script, as opposed to a POSIX `sh` script. Nearly all the `bash`-specific features you are currently using are easily simulated or replaced with standard features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're showing the very beginning of the script, I think it's probably running under regular `sh`.  The `sh` language does not support the `function` keyword ([reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05)).  If you add

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line of your script, so that it runs under `bash`, you should be OK.

Alternatively, you can remove the word `function` from the first line of your script.  However, it's better to add the `#!` so you can make use of the `bash` features.

---

As a test, I tried using `dash` (which doesn't support some of the `bash` extensions) on Cygwin.  The line

```
function foo() {
```

gave me the corresponding error:

```
dash: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

but

```
foo() {
```

worked fine.

Comment: @Nathan30 Glad to hear it!  We've all been there :) .